# Matrix product of two vectors

Tags: swift, simd, metal

I'd like to multiply two vectors - one defined as 3x1 and another as 1x3 - conceptually and get a 3x3 matrix as a result. I use for this purpuse `simd` library. Is there a built-in function to achieve this? Below you can find psuedo code that I'd like to work

```swift
import simd


let v1 = simd_float3(1, 2, 3)
let v2 = simd_float3(4, 5, 6)


/// Is there a function such as matrix_product?
let result: simd_float3x3 = matrix_product(v1, v2)
```

Answer (score 1):

No. You'll have to write it yourself. E.g.

```swift
import simd

public protocol SquareSIMDFloatingPointMatrix {
  associatedtype Vector: SIMD & Collection<Vector.Scalar>
  where Vector.Scalar: FloatingPoint

  init(_ columns: [Vector])
}

public extension SquareSIMDFloatingPointMatrix {
  init(column: Vector, row: Vector) {
    self.init(row.map { column * $0 })
  }
}

extension matrix_float2x2: SquareSIMDFloatingPointMatrix { }
extension matrix_float3x3: SquareSIMDFloatingPointMatrix { }
extension matrix_float4x4: SquareSIMDFloatingPointMatrix { }
extension matrix_double2x2: SquareSIMDFloatingPointMatrix { }
extension matrix_double3x3: SquareSIMDFloatingPointMatrix { }
extension matrix_double4x4: SquareSIMDFloatingPointMatrix { }
```

```swift
public extension SIMD where Self: RandomAccessCollection {
  var startIndex: Int { 0 }
  var endIndex: Int { scalarCount }
}

extension SIMD2: RandomAccessCollection { }
extension SIMD3: RandomAccessCollection { }
extension SIMD4: RandomAccessCollection { }
extension SIMD8: RandomAccessCollection { }
extension SIMD16: RandomAccessCollection { }
extension SIMD32: RandomAccessCollection { }
extension SIMD64: RandomAccessCollection { }
```

*Note: your question is not specific to square matrices. It's just a pain to work with this framework generically, and this seemed a reasonable start.*